# 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1 upgrade using generated patchfile

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0, git

I'm trying to upgrade existing Magento store from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1 using git patchfile, generated by `git format-patch HEAD^`, executed in my "Magento history" repo, where the only commits are Magento releases. So, I've created a patchfile which looks like follows:

```
From --- blah blah blah ---
From: --- blah blah blah ---
Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 14:37:28 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] 1.9.1.0

---
 .htaccess.sample                                   |   178 +
 app/Mage.php                                       |     4 +-
 .../community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/Model/Event.php |    10 +-
 app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Helper/Data.php           |     8 +-
...
...
...
diff --git a/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Helper/Data.php b/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Helper/Data.php
index b7d7673..a118336 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Helper/Data.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Helper/Data.php
@@ -10,18 +10,18 @@
  * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
  * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
  * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
- * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
+ * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
  *
  * DISCLAIMER
  *
  * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
  * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
- * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
+ * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
  *
  * @category    Mage
  * @package     Mage_Admin
- * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
- * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
+ * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
+ * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
  */

 /**
```

Nothing special here at all: when applying the patch, e-mail address and URL in the file comment should be changed. Well, it's not. `git apply` is unable to patch this and any other file, because... "patch failed". 
When I execute `git apply --reject` the explanation I get is:

```
error: while searching for:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
```

Well, it's a bunch of nonsense, because that's *exactly* what's in this file.

Does anyone have any idea, what might be the problem here and why does Git complain here?

Comment: I recommend to ask this question on stackoverflow, because it is about patching and not specific about magento. - If the answer by JELLEJ doesn'T help :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Are you sure that you have the patch in the same directory as your Magento?

What is the command you run?

Please try

```
patch -p1 -i <patchfile>
```

in the directory..